# How to select string Rows from MS SQL Json String array?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

I have a Text String which contains JSON, something like this:

```js
'{ "d" : [ "test0", "test1", "test2" ] }'
```

and I would like to retrieve the item of the Array as rows.

```
+------------+
|   data     | 
+------------+ 
|  test0     | 
|  test1     | 
|  test2     | 
+------------+
```

all examples on the Web, show how it is done with "Object Array", but I would like to do it with a simple "String Array" [MS example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The default query

```sql
select * from OPENJSON('{"d":["test0","test1","test2"]}', '$.d')
```

just returns a table with the key, value, type of each entry

```
+-----+-------+------+
| key | value | type |
+-----+-------+------+
|   0 | test0 |    1 |
|   1 | test1 |    1 |
|   2 | test2 |    1 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

the problem is, I don't know how to set the `with` part of the query, so that the query returns a row.

```sql
select * from OPENJSON('{"d":["test0","test1","test2"]}', '$.d')
with(data nvarchar(255) '$.d')
```

only return:

```
+------+
| data |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
```

Comment: You're almost there -- it should be `with(data nvarchar(255) '$')`, as you want the entire object as the data (the individual strings don't have properties named `d`).

Comment: Why not just `select [value] AS Data from `select [value] AS Data from OPENJSON('{"d":["test0","test1","test2"]}', '$.d')` ?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks works, I had just found it. Thanks anyway. Please post it as answer, so that you get the _accepted Answer_.

Comment: @Zhorov is also an alternative, I didn't think on that. Nice workaround, but I have the `with`solution now. Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from OPENJSON('{"d":["test0","test1","test2"]}', '$.d') 
    with(data nvarchar(255) '$')
```

[image]